# A Common Username for Both Database hosted in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have 2 azure databases created in one SQL Server. I.e.

1. Database 1 = db1 in xsqldb01.database.windows.net
2. Database 2 = db2 in xsqldb01.database.windows.net

I would like to create a username or user login where I can read only data (Select grant only) of both databases. How can I achieve this? Do I need to create a user login with same name in both database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Login in master database using syntax ..

```
CREATE LOGIN <SQL_login_name, sysname, login_name> 
    WITH PASSWORD = '<password, sysname, Change_Password>' 
GO
```

and then create user in individual databases using syntax

```
CREATE USER <user_name, sysname, user_name>
    FOR LOGIN <login_name, sysname, login_name>
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = <default_schema, sysname, dbo>
GO

GRANT SELECT  TO <user_name>
```

This can be done via SSMS from local machine or VM. I believe you can achieve this using Query Editor in Azure as it does not allow switching context to master database .